# get full path to shared directory

Tags: bash, path, cygwin

I have done following

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJDIR="//$HOST/projects"
cd $PROJDIR
newscript

exit 0
```

Purpose of the script is to enter in shared folder and trigger another script 
within it, but the script `newscript` doesn't work if it do not get full path.
Here `$HOST` is machine name,
projects is shared folder on my machine. Its actual path is `C:\Users\vikram\HOME\share`.
I have shared it with advanced sharing options where we can share the folder with some different name. (Here it's `projects`.)

After entering in the directory and after doing `pwd`
I get `//VIKRAM/projects`.
Here I want its actual absolute path in any way.

I am using Windows 10 as OS and Cygwin as terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute your script in current directory. Add to your script this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:./"
```

Or use absolute path:

```
source ${PROJDIR}/newscript
or
. ${PROJDIR}/newscript
```

Comment: Hi spybull, thanks for answering ; but my issue is I need complete expanded path of $PROJDIR to correctly run the newscript. newscript will not work unless it knows the absolute path of projects, newscripts validates the path ; if it is not like : C:\Users\vikram\HOME\share then it will give error, see; projects is shared directory on all my networked machines, it's net share path is //$HOST/projects but on client machine actual absolute path may vary!

Comment: so the prior script need to be such that it will find shared projects directory and then will get it's absolute path on any machine.

Comment: you can try `readlink -f ${PROJDIR}/newscript` but I suspect it will just provide `//$HOST/projects/newscript` as it is a valid path on the machine. Please remember also that `C:\Users\vikram\HOME\share` is `/cygdrive/C/Users/vikram/HOME/share` under Cygwin